# php include different script based on language

Tags: php, if-statement

Here is my question:

I have three different languages in my website:
italian, english and french.

I need to link different .js file for every language. I mean,

```
italian = script for italian language
english = script for english language
french = script for french language
```

Just to be clearer, I have something like this, but I know that is **wrong**:

```
<?php if($lang['LINGUA'] = 'Italiano') { <script src="assets/js/jquery.it.js}
```

Can you help me, please, writing the right code?

Thank you very much :)

Francesca

Comment: Ever heared about `echo`?

Comment: Apart from the PHP syntax errors, why exactly do you think your code is wrong? What have you tried and what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<?php 
if($lang['LINGUA'] == 'Italiano')
{ 
echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.it.js"></script>';
}elseif($lang['LINGUA'] == 'English')
{
echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.en.js"></script>';
}elseif($lang['LINGUA'] == 'French')
{
echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.fr.js"></script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I've used this solution. Works like a charm! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array with your language configurations:

```
$language = Array(
    'Italiano'=>'it',
    'English'='en',
    'French'='fr'
)
```

Then `echo` your HTML, inside quotes, concatenating the array value. You also want a closing script tag. We can even add a check before-hand to ensure the language is available in the array, if not, use `it`:

```
$jqlang = isset($language[$lang['LINGUA']]) ? $language[$lang['LINGUA']] : 'it';
echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.'.$jqlang.'.js"></script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but I think you're on the right track.  Instead of an if statement though, I'd use a switch

```
switch ($lang['LINGUA']){
    case "Italiano":
        //return it.js
        echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.it.js"></script>';
        break;
    case "English":
        //return en.js
        echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.en.js"></script>';
        break;
    case "French":
        //return fr.js
        echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.fr.js"></script>';
        break;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php if(empty($lang['LINGUA'])!==TRUE){
    echo '<script src="assets/js/jquery.'.strtolower($lang['LINGUA']).'.js"></script>';
} ?>
```

It will output `<script src="assets/js/jquery.italiano.js"></script>` in your HTML for the Italian version.

Answer (score 0):

change your $lang['LINGUA'] to equal language abbreviations  such as en,fr,it

then you can do a one liner!

```
$abbrLang = $lang['LINGUA'];

 echo "<script src='assets/js/jquery.$abbrLang.js'></script>";
```

no need for conditional statements